# read multiple CSV and add to list in a loop in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have multiple CSV files and want to read them in R. the file names are provided as an argument, so I don't know the names in advance. This is the reason, why I do it in a loop.

Next, I want each dataframe to be appended to a list. As a result, I want to have an indexed list to access *access the first line of all dataframes* and I think the best way to do this is to have a list of the dataframes available. If there is a more efficient way to do this, any solutions are appreciated.

But for now I will go for the *having all dataframes in a list* approach. For this I would like to know how I can add a dataframe to a list in a loop.

I have this code:

```
#splitting the args to get the filenames
splat <- strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]]
for (fname in splat) {
  #d.fname = dataframe
  d.fname <- read.csv(fname, header = FALSE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
  #code needed to add d.fname to a list?
}
```

So all in all I have two questions:
1) how can I add dataframes to a list in a loop?
2) is there a better way to do this, with the goal in mind, that later I need to have access to all dataframes like *do something (e.g. create a box plot) with the first elements of the first rows of all dataframes*?

I am aware of solutions like this: [Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r) . However, I cannot apply this solution, since I am not able to use `list.files(pattern="*.csv")` because I dont know the filenames in advance.

Comment: you can proceed by `csvNames=strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]]` then you can simply do `lapply(csvNames, read.csv, header=F, sep=',', dec='.')`

Comment: okay neat. can be entered as solution imho.

Comment: next question would be: how to access first elements of first rows of each dataframe in a list?

Comment: May be `lapply(lst, function(x) x[1,1]`

Comment: thanks. and if i first want to do this for the x[1,1] then for x[2,1] etc... how can this be done without a loop? is there a nice way without a for loop?

Comment: `lapply(seq_along(lst) function(x) lst[[x]][x,1])` ... but try to test and understand lapply first ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your original question, you can use directly:

```
lapply(strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]], read.csv, header=F, sep=',', dec='.')
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, you can append to lists in a loop with

```
# Create an empty list
csvList <- list()
#splitting the args to get the filenames
splat <- strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]]
for (fname in splat) {
  #d.fname = dataframe
  d.fname <- read.csv(fname, header = FALSE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
  #code needed to add d.fname to a list?
  csvList[[length(csvList)+1]] <- d.fname
}
```

But I agree `lapply` is much better and will carry the names through. This can be a useful method for more complicated appending when `lapply` might start to struggle.

Answer (score 1):

That might help - too

```
# instantiate an empty list
ldf <- list()

# creates the list of all the csv files in the directory 
# filter for filenames holding UnixM
listcsv <- dir(pattern = ".UnixM.") 

# loop thorugh the list holding the single CSV files
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
   ldf[[k]] <- read.csv(file = listcsv[k]) 
}
```